# ¿Cómo mostar una imagen de un CRUD del backend al frontend?

Tags: crud, backend, yii2, frontend

[image]

Este es el código que estoy usando en el index de producto para que se muestre en el frontend

Comment: Lectura recomendada https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/65107

Comment: Hola, te sugiero leer el apartado "como preguntar?", es necesario que brindes la mayor información posible para ver lo que tienes armado y el código (no en imágenes) para poder hacer pruebas que agilizarán la solución

Comment: Añado el texto y aún así me sigue diciendo que añada texto para mejor explicación y lo hago pero sigue saliendo